# Krsort in php with numbers

Tags: php, numbers, key

I have the following code:

```
foreach ($AR_RESULT_LABNR as $key => $labnr) {
    print_r("<br>");
    print_r($key);
    print_r("<br>");
    print_r($labnr);
    print_r("<br>");
}
```

Why dose php not reverse all keys??

as result I get:

**before:**

225049 L

```
Array ( [ANALYSEDATUM] => 21.07.2020 [ANALYSEUHRZEIT] => 14:21:08 [PARAMETERNAME] => CSB [LABORNUMMER] => 225049 L [BESCHREIBUNG_MESSUNG] => Verbrauch [MASSZAHL_VERBRAUCH] => 4.202 [EINHEIT_VERBRAUCH] => mL [EINMASSWERT] => [EINMASSEINHEIT] => [METHODE] => CSB [MASSZAHL_MESSWERT] => 35.91 [EINHEIT_MESSWERT] => mg/L [RS03NAME] => [RS03WERT] => [RS03EINHEIT] => [ANMERKUNG] => [ANWENDER] => Metrohm16 [MITTELWERT] => 0 )
```

225049 K

```
Array ( [ANALYSEDATUM] => 21.07.2020 [ANALYSEUHRZEIT] => 14:14:45 [PARAMETERNAME] => CSB [LABORNUMMER] => 225049 K [BESCHREIBUNG_MESSUNG] => Verbrauch [MASSZAHL_VERBRAUCH] => 4.151 [EINHEIT_VERBRAUCH] => mL [EINMASSWERT] => [EINMASSEINHEIT] => [METHODE] => CSB [MASSZAHL_MESSWERT] => 38.33 [EINHEIT_MESSWERT] => mg/L [RS03NAME] => [RS03WERT] => [RS03EINHEIT] => [ANMERKUNG] => [ANWENDER] => Metrohm16 [MITTELWERT] => 0 )
```

225013 L

```
Array ( [ANALYSEDATUM] => 21.07.2020 [ANALYSEUHRZEIT] => 14:09:20 [PARAMETERNAME] => CSB [LABORNUMMER] => 225013 L [BESCHREIBUNG_MESSUNG] => Verbrauch [MASSZAHL_VERBRAUCH] => 2.25 [EINHEIT_VERBRAUCH] => mL [EINMASSWERT] => [EINMASSEINHEIT] => [METHODE] => CSB [MASSZAHL_MESSWERT] => 128.83 [EINHEIT_MESSWERT] => mg/L [RS03NAME] => [RS03WERT] => [RS03EINHEIT] => [ANMERKUNG] => [ANWENDER] => Metrohm16 [MITTELWERT] => 0 )
```

225013 K

```
Array ( [ANALYSEDATUM] => 21.07.2020 [ANALYSEUHRZEIT] => 14:04:17 [PARAMETERNAME] => CSB [LABORNUMMER] => 225013 K [BESCHREIBUNG_MESSUNG] => Verbrauch [MASSZAHL_VERBRAUCH] => 2.3 [EINHEIT_VERBRAUCH] => mL [EINMASSWERT] => [EINMASSEINHEIT] => [METHODE] => CSB [MASSZAHL_MESSWERT] => 126.45 [EINHEIT_MESSWERT] => mg/L [RS03NAME] => [RS03WERT] => [RS03EINHEIT] => [ANMERKUNG] => [ANWENDER] => Metrohm16 [MITTELWERT] => 0 )
```

224969 L

```
Array ( [ANALYSEDATUM] => 21.07.2020 [ANALYSEUHRZEIT] => 13:57:51 [PARAMETERNAME] => CSB [LABORNUMMER] => 224969 L [BESCHREIBUNG_MESSUNG] => Verbrauch [MASSZAHL_VERBRAUCH] => 4.5 [EINHEIT_VERBRAUCH] => mL [EINMASSWERT] => [EINMASSEINHEIT] => [METHODE] => CSB [MASSZAHL_MESSWERT] => 21.74 [EINHEIT_MESSWERT] => mg/L [RS03NAME] => [RS03WERT] => [RS03EINHEIT] => [ANMERKUNG] => [ANWENDER] => Metrohm16 [MITTELWERT] => 0 )
```

224969 K

```
Array ( [ANALYSEDATUM] => 21.07.2020 [ANALYSEUHRZEIT] => 13:51:31 [PARAMETERNAME] => CSB [LABORNUMMER] => 224969 K [BESCHREIBUNG_MESSUNG] => Verbrauch [MASSZAHL_VERBRAUCH] => 4.45 [EINHEIT_VERBRAUCH] => mL [EINMASSWERT] => [EINMASSEINHEIT] => [METHODE] => CSB [MASSZAHL_MESSWERT] => 24.08 [EINHEIT_MESSWERT] => mg/L [RS03NAME] => [RS03WERT] => [RS03EINHEIT] => [ANMERKUNG] => [ANWENDER] => Metrohm16 [MITTELWERT] => 0 )
```

Std. 3 200mg/l K

```
Array ( [ANALYSEDATUM] => 21.07.2020 [ANALYSEUHRZEIT] => 13:47:34 [PARAMETERNAME] => CSB [LABORNUMMER] => Std. 3 200mg/l K [BESCHREIBUNG_MESSUNG] => Verbrauch [MASSZAHL_VERBRAUCH] => 0.796 [EINHEIT_VERBRAUCH] => mL [EINMASSWERT] => [EINMASSEINHEIT] => [METHODE] => CSB [MASSZAHL_MESSWERT] => 198.06 [EINHEIT_MESSWERT] => mg/L [RS03NAME] => [RS03WERT] => [RS03EINHEIT] => [ANMERKUNG] => [ANWENDER] => Metrohm16 [MITTELWERT] => 0 )
```

224930 K

```
Array ( [ANALYSEDATUM] => 21.07.2020 [ANALYSEUHRZEIT] => 13:40:35 [PARAMETERNAME] => CSB [LABORNUMMER] => 224930 K [BESCHREIBUNG_MESSUNG] => Verbrauch [MASSZAHL_VERBRAUCH] => 4.9 [EINHEIT_VERBRAUCH] => mL [EINMASSWERT] => [EINMASSEINHEIT] => [METHODE] => CSB [MASSZAHL_MESSWERT] => 2.66 [EINHEIT_MESSWERT] => mg/L [RS03NAME] => [RS03WERT] => [RS03EINHEIT] => [ANMERKUNG] => [ANWENDER] => Metrohm16 [MITTELWERT] => 0 )
```

Result:1

**after:**

Std. 3 200mg/l K

```
Array ( [ANALYSEDATUM] => 21.07.2020 [ANALYSEUHRZEIT] => 13:47:34 [PARAMETERNAME] => CSB [LABORNUMMER] => Std. 3 200mg/l K [BESCHREIBUNG_MESSUNG] => Verbrauch [MASSZAHL_VERBRAUCH] => 0.796 [EINHEIT_VERBRAUCH] => mL [EINMASSWERT] => [EINMASSEINHEIT] => [METHODE] => CSB [MASSZAHL_MESSWERT] => 198.06 [EINHEIT_MESSWERT] => mg/L [RS03NAME] => [RS03WERT] => [RS03EINHEIT] => [ANMERKUNG] => [ANWENDER] => Metrohm16 [MITTELWERT] => 0 )
```

225049 L

```
Array ( [ANALYSEDATUM] => 21.07.2020 [ANALYSEUHRZEIT] => 14:21:08 [PARAMETERNAME] => CSB [LABORNUMMER] => 225049 L [BESCHREIBUNG_MESSUNG] => Verbrauch [MASSZAHL_VERBRAUCH] => 4.202 [EINHEIT_VERBRAUCH] => mL [EINMASSWERT] => [EINMASSEINHEIT] => [METHODE] => CSB [MASSZAHL_MESSWERT] => 35.91 [EINHEIT_MESSWERT] => mg/L [RS03NAME] => [RS03WERT] => [RS03EINHEIT] => [ANMERKUNG] => [ANWENDER] => Metrohm16 [MITTELWERT] => 0 )
```

225049 K

```
Array ( [ANALYSEDATUM] => 21.07.2020 [ANALYSEUHRZEIT] => 14:14:45 [PARAMETERNAME] => CSB [LABORNUMMER] => 225049 K [BESCHREIBUNG_MESSUNG] => Verbrauch [MASSZAHL_VERBRAUCH] => 4.151 [EINHEIT_VERBRAUCH] => mL [EINMASSWERT] => [EINMASSEINHEIT] => [METHODE] => CSB [MASSZAHL_MESSWERT] => 38.33 [EINHEIT_MESSWERT] => mg/L [RS03NAME] => [RS03WERT] => [RS03EINHEIT] => [ANMERKUNG] => [ANWENDER] => Metrohm16 [MITTELWERT] => 0 )
```

225013 L

```
Array ( [ANALYSEDATUM] => 21.07.2020 [ANALYSEUHRZEIT] => 14:09:20 [PARAMETERNAME] => CSB [LABORNUMMER] => 225013 L [BESCHREIBUNG_MESSUNG] => Verbrauch [MASSZAHL_VERBRAUCH] => 2.25 [EINHEIT_VERBRAUCH] => mL [EINMASSWERT] => [EINMASSEINHEIT] => [METHODE] => CSB [MASSZAHL_MESSWERT] => 128.83 [EINHEIT_MESSWERT] => mg/L [RS03NAME] => [RS03WERT] => [RS03EINHEIT] => [ANMERKUNG] => [ANWENDER] => Metrohm16 [MITTELWERT] => 0 )
```

225013 K

```
Array ( [ANALYSEDATUM] => 21.07.2020 [ANALYSEUHRZEIT] => 14:04:17 [PARAMETERNAME] => CSB [LABORNUMMER] => 225013 K [BESCHREIBUNG_MESSUNG] => Verbrauch [MASSZAHL_VERBRAUCH] => 2.3 [EINHEIT_VERBRAUCH] => mL [EINMASSWERT] => [EINMASSEINHEIT] => [METHODE] => CSB [MASSZAHL_MESSWERT] => 126.45 [EINHEIT_MESSWERT] => mg/L [RS03NAME] => [RS03WERT] => [RS03EINHEIT] => [ANMERKUNG] => [ANWENDER] => Metrohm16 [MITTELWERT] => 0 )
```

224969 L

```
Array ( [ANALYSEDATUM] => 21.07.2020 [ANALYSEUHRZEIT] => 13:57:51 [PARAMETERNAME] => CSB [LABORNUMMER] => 224969 L [BESCHREIBUNG_MESSUNG] => Verbrauch [MASSZAHL_VERBRAUCH] => 4.5 [EINHEIT_VERBRAUCH] => mL [EINMASSWERT] => [EINMASSEINHEIT] => [METHODE] => CSB [MASSZAHL_MESSWERT] => 21.74 [EINHEIT_MESSWERT] => mg/L [RS03NAME] => [RS03WERT] => [RS03EINHEIT] => [ANMERKUNG] => [ANWENDER] => Metrohm16 [MITTELWERT] => 0 )
```

224969 K

```
Array ( [ANALYSEDATUM] => 21.07.2020 [ANALYSEUHRZEIT] => 13:51:31 [PARAMETERNAME] => CSB [LABORNUMMER] => 224969 K [BESCHREIBUNG_MESSUNG] => Verbrauch [MASSZAHL_VERBRAUCH] => 4.45 [EINHEIT_VERBRAUCH] => mL [EINMASSWERT] => [EINMASSEINHEIT] => [METHODE] => CSB [MASSZAHL_MESSWERT] => 24.08 [EINHEIT_MESSWERT] => mg/L [RS03NAME] => [RS03WERT] => [RS03EINHEIT] => [ANMERKUNG] => [ANWENDER] => Metrohm16 [MITTELWERT] => 0 )
```

224930 K

```
Array ( [ANALYSEDATUM] => 21.07.2020 [ANALYSEUHRZEIT] => 13:40:35 [PARAMETERNAME] => CSB [LABORNUMMER] => 224930 K [BESCHREIBUNG_MESSUNG] => Verbrauch [MASSZAHL_VERBRAUCH] => 4.9 [EINHEIT_VERBRAUCH] => mL [EINMASSWERT] => [EINMASSEINHEIT] => [METHODE] => CSB [MASSZAHL_MESSWERT] => 2.66 [EINHEIT_MESSWERT] => mg/L [RS03NAME] => [RS03WERT] => [RS03EINHEIT] => [ANMERKUNG] => [ANWENDER] => Metrohm16 [MITTELWERT] => 0 ) 
   
   
$res = krsort($AR_RESULT_LABNR);
print_r('<h2>' . $res . '</h2>');

print_r('<hr>');
foreach ($AR_RESULT_LABNR as $key => $labnr) {
    print_r("<br>");
    print_r($key);
    print_r("<br>");
    print_r($labnr);
    print_r("<br>");
}
```

Comment: Please remove the excess information here. If this is about sorting by _keys_, then all that `Array ( [ANALYSEDATUM] => 21.07.2020 …` stuff is just bloat.

Comment: _“Why dose php not reverse all keys?”_ - you are not _reversing_ the array, you are _sorting_ it. Those are two fundamentally different things to begin with.

Comment: `Std. 3 200mg/l K`,`225049 L`,`225049 K`,`225013 L`,`225013 K`,`224969 L`,`224969 K`,`224930 K` - that’s all your keys, sorted perfectly fine in descending order (using SORT_REGULAR ordering). There appears to be nothing wrong here - apart from your own understanding of what you are actually doing …?